# How to Oauth a petition to a Google App Script Web App?

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-oauth, gcloud

I am making a system to create a Google Form based on a JSON file received via POST. I have already coded and deployed everything in the Google Apps Script Web App system, and have even managed to create the Form when using rested calls through my browser.

But I can not get the Oauth to work from the outside, I have made all types of Oauth credentials, service accounts (both as an owner and as all of the scopes I can think of are used in this case). 
What part of the Google Cloud documentation am I missing? Should I deploy this as an API executable instead?

Comment: Provide [mcve] and error

Comment: Also make sure you've read everything from the added tag info page